xskak can not use arrow. Please check the details of the cause
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}

\newcommand\mychessloop[1][]{%
 \xskakloop[#1]{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }}%

\begin{document}

\centering


Example1 
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe4 5. g3 f6
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\mychessloop

\clearpage

Example2 
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe5 5. b4 a5
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }[![enter image description here][2]][2]
\mychessloop[initmoveid=3w]

\end{document}



why are you using platex as compiler instead of pdflatex or lualatex?? If you are doing that by purpose: I don't know what driver ptex2pdf means, but you need to tell tikz about the backend driver, try with \documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}.

thanks I did that without any problem.
